# Password is defined but doesn't show it is

Tags: php, passwords

Good evening lads and ladies,

I have the following problem
Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\hassan-opdracht\php\register.php on line 71

I looked into it multiple times and my buddy helped me with it but we didn't get any further. So please, help me.

```
<?php
 session_start();

   include("config.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Register Form</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>


<body>


  <form method="POST" action="register.php">
  <td>Name</td><td> <input type="text" name="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Email</td><td> <input type="text" name="email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Phone </td><td><input type="text" name="phone"></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>Password</td><td> <input type="password" name="password"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-Up"></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
  </table>
  </fieldset>
  </div>


  <?php

  if("submit"){
    function NewUser()
    {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone =  $_POST['phone'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO php_users_login (email,password,name,phone) VALUES ('$email','$password','$name','$phone')";
    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if($data)
    {
    echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
    }
    }

    function SignUp()
    {
    if(!empty($_POST['email']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-Up.html, is it empty or have some text
    {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM php_users_login WHERE `email` = '$_POST[email]' AND `password` = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()))
    {
    newuser();
    }
    else
    {
    echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...";
    }
    }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    SignUp();
    }

  }
  else{
    echo "didn't work.";
  }
  ?>
```

this is my code, NOTE : i'm not very advanced in coding so please be patient

Thank you in advance, 
Kind regards
Damian

Answer (score 0):

First, you check `if("submit")` which is always true, you probably want to do `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`.

Second, the mysql extension is deprecated and you have some serious SQL Injection vulnerabilities in your code. Take a look at [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for safe database access.

Third, you wouldn't need to wrap your sign up code in a function if you don't use it anywhere else. It's also considered bad practice to get global variables like `$_POST` from inside a function. You could either pass in all `$_POST` variables via arguments or just don't put it in a function.

You should also check if a `$_POST` value exists before you access it, you can use `array_key_exists('name', $_POST)` to do that. Make sure to always handle user data as if it could be broken or infected with bad code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that form is submitted and then you can try to use `$_POST` array.

```
if(isset($_POST['password'])){ $password = $_POST['password']; }
```

> Note :- the mysql_* functions have been removed in PHP7. Use MySQLi
>   instead.

Hope it helps! :)